# OpenGL How can I hide surface ? (LWJGL)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm writing boxes left to right with `openGL(LWGJL)`

The left side color of box is green and right side is blue.

Now please see below picture.

Left side of boxes are shown shown as below.

[image]

The left side must not be shown , but it shown.
I tried Depth-Test but it was not worked.

How can I hide left side?
Do I have to consider sequence of writing box?

please see my code.

```
package lwjgltest;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;

public class DrawMotion {
    private int         width = 1200;
    private int         height = 700;
    private int         depth = 800;

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
            Display.setTitle("boxtest");
            Display.create();
        } catch(LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

            glCullFace(GL_BACK);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();

           gluPerspective(45f,width/height,0,depth);
          glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                render();
                Display.update();
           }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Display.destroy();
        }
    }

    private float x=0;
    private float y=-100;
    private float z=-800;
    private void render() {
        for(int i=0;i<52;i++){

            glLoadIdentity();

            glTranslatef(-300+(i*1)+i*2.8f*2*2, y, z);

            glScalef(2.8f,2.8f,2.8f);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);

            for (Face face: Face.values()) {
                face.draw();
            }

            glEnd();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawMotion().start();
    }
 }
```

This is good because there is distance between 2 boxes.
[image]

If 2 boxes is closed left side of right box should be hidden but it shown

[image]

This is what I want to do.
(I reverse to drawing order in this picture.I want to show correctly without drawing order)

[image]

Comment: You absolutely have to enable the depth test.

Answer (score 0):

That is the left side? It looks like the right side to me.

Either way, you cannot pass a value of **0** to `gluPerspective (...)` for **zNear** or **zFar**. You have basically made your depth buffer useless by introducing division by zero to your projection matrix.

```
    zFar     (depth)
r = ----  =   -----   =  oo
    zNear    ( 0.0 )

Precision Loss (in bits)  = log2 r =  oo  ==>  (NO DEPTH BUFFER PRECISION!)
```

#### Consider this instead:

```
gluPerspective(45f,width/height,0.01f,depth); // All values must be positive!
                                              //  (ZERO is not positive)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've changed zNear to 0.01f but problem not solved.

Left side should be hidden but it is shown.
Please see added screen shot.

Comment: @KenichiTakematsu: Add `glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST)`; And then your problems should go away.